# More than one sprite in Spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a few related questions that I have been wondering about:

1. Can you have more than one sprite in Sprite kit, so you can have multiple characters in your game where the user purchases them?
2. Is there any tutorial online that shows how you can have more than one sprite in Sprite kit (if you can)?
3. Can the user buy the sprites with game points, and is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: 1. Yes - SK programs can have more that one sprite on screen at once. 2. Yes - try Ray Wenderlich's site for some excellent SK tutorials. 3. Yes - this is something you'd implement in your game logic.

Comment: @Ahmed Welcome to SO. You can read this tutorial to help you to make a better question because , for rules, you shouldn't ask for tutorials: :http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Anyway , Mina gave you a good resource to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can have more than one sprite in your scene. you can start with this [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1) tutorial.
you can design an algorithm to add sprites to your scene, when the user reach to the exact point. There is another [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143258/make-waiting-game-like-farmville-spritekit-swift)  tutorial, which built a game like farmville, with selling option.

Comment: Is there a tutorial which shows me how to have a game store where user can buy sprites with game points ?

Comment: Raywenderlich has another tutorial for exactly what you want, a game like [farmville](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143258/make-waiting-game-like-farmville-spritekit-swift) with store.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano this is a general question, it's better for Ahmed  to read tutorials and get familiar with the logics.

Comment: @Mina [Links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I really appreciate the help. I'm only 14 and learning by myself, so I'm sorry if I sound like a noob in sprite kit because I was making normal applications for the past year and I made the switch now.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano thanks to notice. I will be more carefull about it.

Comment: Ahmed, i'm so happy to hear that you are only 14. I am always saying that learn what ever you want, from the begining, and now it's a good time for you to learn game programming from the beginnig. I will update my response and give you more information about the tutorial.